# RXSwift Zip operator N items via an enumerable

Tags: ios, swift, rx-java, rx-swift

I'm using RxSwift's [`zip`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) operator to combine `Observable` items. I want to combine more than 8 (the max currently supported). Does RxSwift have a `zip` operator similar to RxJava? - [RxJava Zip Operator Documentation](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#zip(java.lang.Iterable,%20rx.functions.FuncN))

Comment: So did the answer below satisfy your question?  I'm not sure why you haven't accepted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can handle more than 8 if you use it on `CollectionType`.

[Here's the method definition](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/5a112ed0640ec2dae8aaf04391a5e95f6190ae51/RxSwift/Observables/Observable+Multiple.swift#L42):

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element : ObservableType {
    public func zip<R>(resultSelector: [Generator.Element.E] throws -> R) -> Observable<R> {
        return ZipCollectionType(sources: self, resultSelector: resultSelector)
    }
}
```

So instead of using it like this:

```
Observable.zip(o1, o2, o3, o4, o5, o6, o7, o8, o9) { ... }
```

Use it like this:

```
[o1, o2, o3, o4, o5, o6, o7, o8, o9].zip { ... }
```

Comment: This is interesting, are there any side affects to this?

Comment: No side affects. It behaves like `Observable.zip`.

Comment: If I am reading that right, it treats the collection as a set of source observables then zips them as they get emitted? Is that correct?

Comment: This answer doesn't compile with Swift 3.1 and RxSwift 3.4.1. could you please update it?

Comment: The above is no longer compiling with Xcode 12. Has any one else ran into this issue?